# how to set Cancel button when you press it in pyProgress

Tags: python, wxpython

Hello I use `wxpython 4` and `windows10`.I want to integrate `PyProgress (AGW)` in my App with the `Cancel button` and I would like this button `Cancel` put my App `Paused`. except that I have add the cancel button but it is not clickable and I can not Bind a pause function with this button.

```
import wx.lib.agw.pyprogress as PP

def onButton(self, event):
        """
        Based on the wxPython demo by the same name
        """
        event.Skip()
        dlg = PP.PyProgress(None, -1, "Demo", "Demo in progress", agwStyle=wx.PD_APP_MODAL | wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME | wx.PD_CAN_ABORT)
        dlg.SetGaugeProportion(0.2)
        dlg.SetGaugeSteps(50)
        dlg.SetGaugeBackground(wx.WHITE)
        dlg.SetFirstGradientColour(wx.WHITE)
        dlg.SetSecondGradientColour(wx.BLUE)
        max = 400
        keepGoing = True
        count = 0

        while keepGoing and count < max:
            count += 1
            wx.MilliSleep(30)

            if count >= max / 2:
                keepGoing = dlg.UpdatePulse("Half-time!")
            else:
                keepGoing = dlg.UpdatePulse()

        dlg.Destroy()

#if(wx.PD_CAN_ABORT):
#execute onPause(event)


def onPause(self, event):
???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyProgress` no longer appears to have an operational `Cancel` button.
Use `wx.ProgressDialog` or `wx.Gauge` instead.

If you don't want a pause function use something like this:

```
import wx

class PyProgressDemo(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.startbutton = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Start PyProgress!")
        self.startbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.startbutton)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Show()

    def onButton(self, event):
            self.dlg = wx.ProgressDialog('Search personal Data', 'Analyse en cours..', style= wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME | wx.PD_CAN_ABORT)
            max = 400
            keepGoing = True
            count = 0
            while keepGoing and count < max:
                count += 1
                wx.MilliSleep(30)

                if count >= max / 2:
                    (keepGoing, skip) = self.dlg.Pulse("Half-time!")
                else:
                    (keepGoing, skip) = self.dlg.Pulse()

            self.dlg.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
prog = PyProgressDemo(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

If you want a `Pause` function, I think that you will have to use the `Freeze` option, something like this:

```
import wx

class PyProgressDemo(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.startbutton = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Start PyProgress!")
        self.stopbutton = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Pause/Unpause PyProgress!")
        self.startbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        self.stopbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPause)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.startbutton)
        vbox.Add(self.stopbutton)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Show()

    def onButton(self, event):
            self.dlg = wx.ProgressDialog('Search personal Data', 'Analyse en cours..', style= wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME | wx.PD_CAN_ABORT)
            max = 400
            keepGoing = True
            count = 0

            try:
                while keepGoing and count < max:
                    if self.dlg.IsFrozen():
                        wx.Yield()
                        wx.MilliSleep(30)
                        continue
                    count += 1
                    wx.MilliSleep(30)

                    if count >= max / 2:
                        (keepGoing, skip) = self.dlg.Pulse("Half-time!")
                    else:
                        (keepGoing, skip) = self.dlg.Pulse()

                self.dlg.Destroy()
            except:
                pass

    def onPause(self, event):
        try:
            if self.dlg.IsFrozen():
                self.dlg.Thaw()
            else:
                self.dlg.Freeze()
        except:
            pass

app = wx.App()
prog = PyProgressDemo(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Now I want to change the word "Cancel" to "Pause" and add two more buttons (Restart, Other) on the "ProgressDialog".even if you have to modify the source code of the library. I would. but please tell me where to find the file to edit.

Comment: @LandryEngolo You are going to have to read up on python `subclassing`, as you want to subclass the progressdialog.